# Need your help: I have this query resulting in an array and I wish to have the array length. Can't find the right syntax for doing that

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have this query which results in an array.

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT (journeys.id)FROM JOURNEYS JOIN RESPONSES ON scenarios[1] = responses.id WHERE channel_name = 'channel1' ORDER BY journeys.id) AS journey_id;
```

I need only the array_length but I can't figure out what is the syntax for that.

Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: If you only need the length, why make it an array at all? Why not just run the nested SQL as `select count(*) from...`?

Comment: Yes you are correct @David784. The problem is I did not know how to do that.
Well, your question helped me search further with the right terminology and I did find a solution.
Indeed there is no need to user the Array at all